# Override Native iOS Video Player done button

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview, html5-video

Hi I have an html5 video player on my UIWebView, as you may know when I click on the play button the native video player takes control, how can I override the "done" button so I can close the video when its pressed? Thanks! – Claire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I learned that you can't override the done button when using a UIWebView. My workaround was to add a close button to the UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, for there's nothing in UIWebView which allows you to do that, UIWebView is actually thought to be pretty closed and straightforward.

[UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)